# String '‎2019-04-01' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. OR always getting "false" if try to parse it to DateTime

Tags: datetime, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

I'm getting below exception while converting string to datetime in Fluent Validation (.net core)

**Error**: System.FormatException: 'String '‎2019-04-01' was not recognized as a valid DateTime OR always getting "false" if try to parse it to DateTime.

**Request payload**:

```
{
    "opened": "‎2019-04-01"
}
```

**Fluent Validator Rule**:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Opened).Must(BeAValidDate).WithMessage("Invalid Opened date");
```

**Class function**:

```
public bool BeAValidDate(string value)
        {
            DateTime output;
            bool bOutput;
            //option 1
            bOutput = DateTime.TryParse(value, out output);

            //option 2
            //bOutput = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out output);

            //option 3
            //try
            //{
            //    output = DateTime.Parse(value);
            //    bOutput = true;
            //}
            //catch {
            //    bOutput = false;
            //}
            return bOutput;
        }
```

Tried all above three option but always getting false/exception.

And the weird part is if I pass the static value then it works fine e.g. instead of value if I pass the variable e.g.

```
string value = '2019-04-01';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace for the exception and the definition of your class or at least the Opened property. A manual (server-side) invocation of your validator works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the variable "value" before parsing it and converting it to DateTime.
It is possible that the string you parse has soome unwanted caracters.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for responding! I don't know exactly what was the actual issue but when I manually entered the date in postman request, It worked.